# How do I testfor if a player is standing on a certain block on a certain coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm pretty new to testfor still and I would like to know how to create a commandblock system that would detect when they are standing on a yellow wool block on the coordinates 400 4 600 (for example) does anyone know how to setup this redstone suystem, and also be specific about how I set the redstone system up, so for example show me a picture on how the setup of it would look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a redstone clock with a command block as shown below:
[image: How to set up]

In the command block add the command `/testfor @a[x=400,y=4,z=Z,r=600]` and start up your clock. When ever a user is at that location, the red output line as shown in the picture will power. Once they have left the position, the output will power off.

Comment: This will test for players at that location, but not whether or not they are standing on yellow wool.

Comment: But if the yellow wool is at that location, surely it'll be fine. OP hasn't mentioned the wool moving?

Comment: Depends; OP's question isn't really clear about it. It could be that the yellow wool just happens to be at those coords and it isn't necessary to detect it, but I understood it as only wanting to detect people who are standing on yellow wool, which may or may not be at those coords.

Comment: I only wanted to know if I could use testfor to see if a certain person is standing on a not moving yellow block wool, so the yellow block wool is solid, so if someone is standing on the yellow block wool, will the command then activate the redstone system and the command within the /testfor itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a command like this:

```
execute @a[x=400,y=4,z=600] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:wool 4 [Command]
```

For [Command], you can do something like `scoreboard players set @p dummyobjective 1`

Then `execute @a[score_dummyobjective_min=1] ~ ~ ~ [command]`

But those last two lines are usually only needed if you want to run multiple commands, or to keep track of multiple players.

Comment: I'm not really familia with the redstone system that is used for execute, would you be able to show me a picture on how it would activate exactly, and what redstone system would be used for it?

Comment: Not currently, but if you give me a while I can. I'm not able to play at the moment. If you could supply what you want to do when a player stands on the block, I can fill in the command for you. After that, it's just a matter of having a redstone clock activate a command block with the command above inside of it.

Comment: Also, if you want the command to activate no matter where he is in the world, just remove the '[x=400,y=4,z=600]'.

Comment: Give me a picture of the redstone system I would be using for this command